# Bing text translator API returns "response for preflight is invalid"

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I try to translate with microsoft/bing text translator api. I have an azure service and valid token from /v1.0/issueToken.

I tried this in my browser and on this testsite: https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate

```
text=test
to=en
Authorization=Bearer TOKEN
```

That's what i got back:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?text=test&to=en. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

> => "error": "no response from server"

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working if "Bearer "+ TOKEN is added via appid parameter. Authorization header doesn't work in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using `curl` and Windows. Looks like you're missing `From` query parameter. Always prototype API calls using `curl`before integrating. If it doesn't work with `curl`, it won't work in your code. Use curl first.

```
curl -k --data "" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<Your key here>" > Bearer.txt
set /p Bearer= < Bearer.txt
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?Text=test&From=en&To=es"
```